# A lot of connection directed to otelrules.azureedge.net

Tags: azure

Good Morning

Starting from a couple of days, I have found on our proxy server a lot of connection sessions to this address otelrules.azureedge.net

I could not figure out what this site stands for, whether it is an official Microsoft site or not and google was of no help in solving my question. Do you know this site? It's safe? Or should the origins of the connections be investigated and eventually blocked?

Thanks for your help

I tried googling information about this site but to no avail. I have not found anything that could be useful to understand if the site is malicious or not

Answer (score 0):

Upon monitoring the traffic on my computer, I have ascertained that this address emanates from Microsoft Office applications.

Upon conducting research and scrutinizing the traffic, I have deduced that this address pertains to an Office telemetry. You may either block the address or take no action at all. It is not an unfamiliar or untrusted connection.

When launching the Office application (such as Word or Excel), the request appears as follows:

```
    GET /rules/winword.exe-Production-v19.bundle HTTP/2
Host: otelrules.azureedge.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Word 16.0.16227; Pro)
```

As the response is excessively lengthy, I shall supplement it with a succinct illustration.

```
    HTTP/2 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Md5: D6m+pag+uTEtTF0eLQl3oQ==
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Apr 2023 09:14:33 GMT
Etag: 0x8DB3B365499846A
X-Cache: TCP_HIT
X-Ms-Request-Id: 3735bead-301e-0038-01dc-70acf8000000
X-Ms-Version: 2009-09-19
X-Ms-Lease-Status: unlocked
X-Ms-Blob-Type: BlockBlob
X-Azure-Ref-Originshield: 08/U9ZAAAAAAiDHpTFBQVRLHsyHtiKjNeRlJBMjMxMDUwNDE3MDMxAGRjMWIzZDM1LTU5OTgtNDRkYy1hOTc2LThmZjI4ZjE2YjM3Yw==
X-Azure-Ref: 0gz8+ZAAAAABq4qCGpR+mR5Cbje7OCSayRlJBMjMxMDUwNDE5MDM5AGRjMWIzZDM1LTU5OTgtNDRkYy1hOTc2LThmZjI4ZjE2YjM3Yw==
Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 06:58:10 GMT

100042v2+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<R Id="100042" V="2" DC="SM" EN="Office.UX.Desktop.OfficeTheme.App.Init" ATT="c4388c977297413bb054bad1acf0ade1-cc58e53e-f5a4-4f37-b0d2-9a8079e34420-6879" DCa="PSU" xmlns="">
  <S>
    <UTS T="1" Id="cm9y5" A="a24c8" />
  </S>
  <C T="FT" I="0" O="false" N="CollectionTime">
    <S T="1" F="TimeStamp100ns" />
  </C>
  <C T="U32" I="1" O="false" N="OfficeTheme">
    <S T="1" F="OfficeTheme" />
  </C>
  <T>
    <S T="1" />
  </T>
</R>
<$!#>100043v0+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<R Id="100043" V="0" DC="SM" EN="Office.UX.Desktop.OfficeTheme.Changed.Through.UI" ATT="c4388c977297413bb054bad1acf0ade1-cc58e53e-f5a4-4f37-b0d2-9a8079e34420-6879" SP="CriticalBusinessImpact" DCa="PSU" xmlns="">
  <S>
    <UTS T="1" Id="a24db" />
  </S>
  <C T="FT" I="0" O="false" N="CollectionTime">
    <S T="1" F="TimeStamp100ns" />
  </C>
  <C T="U32" I="1" O="false" N="OfficeTheme">
    <S T="1" F="OfficeTheme" />
  </C>
  <T>
    <S T="1" />
  </T>
</R>
<$!#>100068v2+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<R Id="100068" V="2" DC="SM" EN="Office.UX.WhatsNewCantOpen" ATT="c4388c977297413bb054bad1acf0ade1-cc58e53e-f5a4-4f37-b0d2-9a8079e34420-6879" DCa="PSU" xmlns="">
  <S>
    <UTS T="1" Id="bbqss" />
  </S>
  <C T="FT" I="0" O="false" N="CollectionTime">
    <S T="1" F="TimeStamp100ns" />
  </C>
  <C T="W" I="1" O="false" N="Reasons">
    <S T="1" F="Reasons" />
  </C>
  <T>
    <S T="1" />
  </T>
</R>
<$!#>100069v1+<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<R Id="100069" V="1" DC="SM" EN="Office.UX.WhatsNewTimeOnScreen" ATT="c4388c977297413bb054bad1acf0ade1-cc58e53e-f5a4-4f37-b0d2-9a8079e34420-6879" SP="CriticalBusinessImpact" DCa="PSU" xmlns="">
  <S>
    <UTS T="1" Id="bbqsl" />
    <UTS T="2" Id="bbqsm" />
  </S>
  <C T="FT" I="0" O="false" N="CollectionTime">
    <S T="2" F="TimeStamp100ns" />
  </C>
  <C T="I64" I="1" O="false" N="WhatsNewOnScreenTimeSec">
    <O T="DIV">
      <L>
        <O T="SUB">
          <L>
            <S T="2" F="TimeStamp100ns" />
          </L>
          <R>
            <S T="1" F="TimeStamp100ns" />
          </R>
        </O>
      </L>
      <R>
        <V V="10000000" T="U64" />
      </R>
    </O>
  </C>
  <T>
    <S T="2" />
  </T>
</R>
```